# python sql query with variable

Tags: python, mysql

```
testid = 69
query = """SELECT * FROM basic_info WHERE ownerid=%s"""
cur.execute(query, testid)
print cur.fetchone()
```

I am getting an integer error when attempting this. I have tried converting testid to a string with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this method of inserting parameters since it's very clear:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM basic_info WHERE ownerid = %(testid)s"
cur.execute(query, params = { 'testid': testid })
```

Answer (score 0):

The second paraemter of [`Cursor.execute`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id14) should be a sequence (`tuple` or `list`) or a mapping (`dict`):

```
testid = 69
query = """SELECT * FROM basic_info WHERE ownerid=%s"""
cur.execute(query, [testid])  # <--
print cur.fetchone()
```